# Angular 2: multiple <router-outlet> for sub routes

Tags: javascript, angular

With Angular 2, is it any way to have sub route not displaying into the main tag

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

For example :

```
url : "http://mywebsite.com/"
MainComponent.ts
@Component({
    ...
    template:'<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
    ...
})
@RouteCongif([
    {path: '/products', name:'Product', component: Product}
])
```

This displays the sub component into the <router-outlet> tag

All right, now is it possible to have this kind of configuration :

```
url : "http://mywebsite.com/products"
ProductComponent.ts
@Component({
    template: `
        ...
        <div> My list of products ! </div>
        ...
        <a [RouteLink]="['ProductDetails', {slug-product-details:product.slug}]"> 
           {{ product.name }} Details 
        </a>
        ...
        <sub-router-outlet></sub-router-outlet>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
     {path: '/:slug-product-details', name:'ProductDetails', component: ProductDetailsComponent},
])
```

And

```
url : "http://mywebsite.com/products/one-product-details"
ProductDetailsComponent.ts
@Component({
    ...
    template : `
         <div> Details of the product : </div>
         ...
    `
    ...
})
```

I want to keep the usage of the router with the auto designed url and diplay the route and the details template into this sort of <sub-router-outlet> tag.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have a nested router-outlet sample her if that helps: https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/blob/master/app.ts and https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/blob/master/demo-page.ts There is a demo here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/graph

Comment: It seems to be what i am looking for :) Thank you.

Comment: Just a question about the demo. Does the hash in url inevitable?

Comment: Nested routing is described in the [Routing dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) page.  Just look for "Child Routing Component".

Comment: There might be different url conventions, but haven't played with them yet. Here is how I configure it: bootstrap(MyDemoApp,[AddressBookTitleService,ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,
          provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);

Comment: FYI - router is under heavy development atm. I wouldn't invest much energy into understanding it's current implementation just yet

Answer (score 6):

**WARNING:** The code below only works on Angular2 Beta

You can implement sub routing. Your file structure should be similar like this.

**app.ts**

```
@RouteConfig([
    ...
    { path: '/product/...', component: Product, name: 'Product'}
    { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home'}
    ...
])
export class App { }
```

**product.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
   ...
   { path: 'product-one', component: ProductOne, name: 'Product-one' },        
   { path: 'product-two', component: ProductTwo, name: 'Product-two', useAsDefault: true },
   ...
])
export class Product {
    constructor(location: Location, public router: Router) {}

    goToProductOne() {
        this.router.navigate(['Product','Product-one'])
    }
}
```

**product.html**

```
...
<a [routerLink]="['./Product-one']"> Product One </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Home']"> Home </a>
...
```

Where ['./Product-one'] is a subroute and ['/Home'] is a parent route

Comment: does is support in final @2.0.0 (not alpha, beta or rc)