# How to implement multi-level routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm working on a little project of mine in order to learn something more about Angular, but I really cannot figure out how to implement a multi-leveled routing.

I've read the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) about the new release of the Router Component and also some other topics on StackOverlfow ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050283/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-level-nested-route-in-angular2), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233807/angular-2-routing-multi-layer-menus), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439401/angular-2-multiple-router-outlet-for-sub-routes)), but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Let's consider the following **app structure**, without considering the *Test* and *Test2* blocks.

[image: App structure]

And let's consider the components of my app as following:

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { MyAppComponent } from './my-app/my-app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './my-app/my-app.routes';

bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [ APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS ])
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**my-app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class MyAppComponent { }
```

**my-app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';

import { AdminRoutes} from './admin/admin.routes';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
  ...AdminRoutes,
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    template: 'Hello I am ADMIN <br> <router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AdminComponent { }
```

**admin.routes.ts**

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page/main-page.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';

export const AdminRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
      path: 'admin',
      component: AdminComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'main-page', component: MainPageComponent },
        { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
      ]
  }
];
```

**main-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-page',
    template: 'Hello I am MAIN PAGE!!!'
})

export class MainPageComponent { }
```

**settings.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'settings',
    template: 'Hello I am SETTINGS!!!'
})

export class SettingsComponent { }
```

When I try to use such a configuration nothing works anymore and the browser's console is full of errors.

This happens only when I add the **children[...]** in the **admin.routes.ts**, and I think the problems come in there.

1. Could you give me any hint on how I can implemented properly, please?
2. Am I missing anything?
3. Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance for your help and I hope what I've written in the post it's helpful to understand my issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular router considers a route with children as a non-terminal route and routing happens to terminal routes only. 
 Angular router expects route to have a default entry for `path: ''`.

To resolve this issue you should add a redirect from the parent route to one of the child routes.

```
export const AdminRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'main-page', terminal: 'true' },
        { path: 'main-page', component: MainPageComponent,
        { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
    ]
 }];
```

Edit: if using rc4 and router 3.0.0-beta2 they have renamed `terminal` to `pathMatch`. So update the redirect route as below:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'main-page', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Comment: You made my day dude, thank you! **Just a last question:** By using your solution, when I try to load the */admin* route, it also loads the */test*. How can I tell to my app to load */test* only when the user wants so?

Comment: It should not unless you have added it to be part of default route (terminal). Show me the updated router config for admin and below

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong... You're right I can't do such a thing! **Can I apply this concept to other sub-routers, in order to achieve *n* levels of routing? Is that a good practice?**

Comment: Yes you can and you should

Comment: Thanks for the version with the updated router - really helped me out!