# Angular2 child routes not working

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm using @angular rc4 `"@angular/router": "^3.0.0-beta.2"`

I haven't been able to get child routes work, when i start adding child routes i get many kinds of errors: 
Here's my route code:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'parentComp'},
{ path: 'parentComp', component: parentContainer, 
        children: [
            {path: 'componenta', component: ComponentA }
        ]
    }
```

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of
>   Router!.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.js:84BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @
>   browser_adapter.js:94ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.js:65(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.js:337schedulerFn @
>   async.js:139SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.js:127onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @
>   ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:259ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423 browser_adapter.js:84
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: Invalid route configuration of route
>   '{path: "", redirectTo: "activity"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The
>   default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to
>   use 'full'.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.js:74(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.js:337schedulerFn @
>   async.js:139SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.js:127onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @
>   ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:259ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423 browser_adapter.js:84
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.js:77(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.js:337schedulerFn @
>   async.js:139SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.js:127onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @
>   ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:259ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423

So i add the pathMatch:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'parentComp', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'parentComp', component: ActivityContainer, 
    children: [
        {path: 'componenta', component: ComponentA }
    ]
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> app/bootstrapper.routes.ts(5,7): error TS2322: Type '({ path: string;
>   redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component:
>   typeof pare...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.   Type '{ path:
>   string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string;
>   component: typeof paren...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.

I realized that many of the answers written were about making sure to use the right version, but I'm using the right latest one for routes just as in angular.io 
So I also have router-deprecated along with it to decrease the number of errors that appear but still, I wasn't able to get the child routes working.

I'm having my shell which will load in its router-outlet the routes, but the minute i go to child routes nothing work. 
Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Angular router considers a route with children as a non-terminal route and routing happens to terminal routes only. Angular router expects route to have a default entry for path: ''. Son in your case you should add below code in children array

```
children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: componenta, pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
```

Moreover whenever we use `redirectTo` the pathMatch strategy should be `full` as we want exact path match to redirect. If we keep `prefix`(not specifiy then default to prefix ) this would cause angular to match a lot of routes to that entry and cause various error.

See this question for further [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172693/652850)

You should get rid of any import of router-deprecated as the error points to mismatch between route declaration and route provider. 
You need use below code in bootstrap componet to provide routers.

```
provideRouter(routes)// routes is array of routes defined in your code.
```

Also have a look at great [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html). The article is on alpha8 version but beta2 have no major change except `terminal:true` is replaced by `pathMatch:full`

Comment: tried these solutions. none worked. added code to children array, had all pathMatch:full, no imports of router-deprecated and provideRouter(routes) is in my bootstrap component. none worked.

Comment: add a plunker with issue, it should be working as far as i know. set up plunker like this http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: it worked for me after I did this `{path : '' , redirectTo : '/home' ,pathMatch: 'full' }`

Answer (score 0):

Try `redirectTo: '/parentComp'` instead of `redirectTo: 'parentComp'`.

Answer (score 0):

The component class name should be written in upper camel case and end in the word "Component". The tutorial explains this in one of their first sections: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html.

The example in their application:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-detail',
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
}
```

Then then adding it to the router:

```
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
```

Try changing your component class names and recompiling

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what You are trying to do here.

This is what works for me:

```
{
    path: 'object', --> base path
    component: ObjectComponent, --> parent component, need to end with "Component"
    children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'childa', pathMatch: 'full'}, --> subpath default, this would redirect "domain/object" to "domain/object/childa"
        {path: 'childa', component: AComponent}, --> this would load AComponent into router-outlet tag and set Your path to "domain/object/childa"
        {path: 'childb', component: BComponent}, --> this would load BComponent into router-outlet tag  and set Your path to "domain/object/childb"
    ]
```

Basically I believe You need to set Your root (path: '') redirection as a child node.

This is ObjectComponent template part:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/object', 'childb']">Child B</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also @Arpit Agarwal answer gives You a lot if detail about inner workings...