# Angular2 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm currently experiencing a problem with my Angular2 app when using the `router.navigateByUrl` method. I have a function in my component called `goToRoute`, it looks like so:

```
router.goToRoute(route:string, event?:Event):void {
        if (event) {
            if (event.defaultPrevented) {
                return;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        this.router.navigateByUrl(route); // prefixing with '/' does nothing here...
        // if the menu has been clicked and it was open close it!
        if (this.menuOpen) {
            this.toggleHamburger();
```

}
    }

I would use this in an `ngFor` in my HTML like so...

```
<div *ngFor="let route of routes ">
    <div (click)="goToRoute(route.path, $event)"> {{ route.display }} </div>
</div>
```

Now when I click a div I get the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about-us'
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: 'about-us' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about-us'(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about-us'(…)
```

This is strange as in my routes I have the following (`DisplayRoutes` is a custom type I made by extending the Route object):

```
export const routes:DisplayRoutes = [
    {
        path: '',
        display: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent
    }, {
        path: 'about-us',
        display: 'About us',
        component: LeftSubNavigation,
        index: {
            component: DetailMoreLayout
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: DetailMoreLayout
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: 'teams',
        display: 'Teams',
        component: LeftSubNavigation,
        index: {
            component: DetailMoreLayout
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: DetailMoreLayout
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

As you can see I do have a route called 'about-us'! For some reason, despite the match of names the paths aren't being matched? I put a console log in my goToRoute method to output the `route` and `event` to see what was being passed... I got this...

```
about-us MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1809, screenY: 382, clientX: 42, clientY: 144…}
```

I am currently switching from the `"@ngrx/router": "^1.0.0-beta.1"` to `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"`. I have a base tag, just things seem to crash when I use `router.navigateByUrl`. I then noticed the same would happen should I deep link, for example when I go to http://localhost:4200/about-us in the browser.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Okay so it is not the prefix `/`, I'm out of suggestions then, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have prefix '/' there.

Secondly, as about-us is non terminating route (has children) you need to define a children with `''(empty)` path. It may redirect to any existing routes.

```
{path: '', redirectTo: 'other-path', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Secondly I assume your extension will take care of display and index var  in config as it is not there in default Routes type.

Have a look at official [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Another so question detailing how to use [multi level routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172693/652850).

Comment: Hi there, the prefix creates an error but I think adding the redirect has made the routing functional.